# Firebase - Unable to login to facebook auth

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to move to my new view controller after the auth is complete and the user has loged into facebook but I get a error saying "Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."" I've looked over the documentation and it looks right to me but maybe I'm missing something. Here is my code for my facebook login button

```
@IBAction func FacebookBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let login = FBSDKLoginManager()

    login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (facebookError != nil) {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error: \(facebookError)")
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            print("Cancelled")
        } else {
            let acessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            print("Logged in. \(acessToken)")

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print("Login failed. \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Logged in. \(user)")

                    let userData = ["provider": credential.provider]
                    DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(user!.uid, user: userData)

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user!.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: nil) // currently not working
                }

            })
```

Full Error log:

> (Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has
>   occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa702c55080 {Error
>   Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={type = immutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>    0 : {contents =
>   "message"} = {contents =
>   "Project marked for deletion."}   1 : errors = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (    0 :
>   {type = immutable dict,
>   count = 4, entries =>     1 : message = {contents = "Project marked for deletion."}     3 : reason
>   = {contents = "accessNotConfigured"}   4 : domain = {contents = "usageLimits"}  5 : {contents = "extendedHelp"} = {contents = "https://console.developers.google.com"} }
>
> )}    2 : code = {value =
>   +403, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type} } }}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal
>   error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more
>   information.})

Comment: only this log or something more ?

Comment: @Shubhank Right now facebook login is the only log I have on the app but the full error log is posted

Comment: it says `accessNotConfigured` did you enable facebook login for your app ?

Comment: @Shubhank Yeah it allows me to login it looks like when I click the button and it says I'm already signed in and everything. It appears to be working.

Comment: Also it gives me my auth token in the console, so it must be enabled, right? @Shubhank

Comment: yup.. does the normal login work ? there is also "Project marked for deletion" log which i am not sure what does it specify.

Comment: Yeah normal facebook login works but I don't know what that means either. @Shubhank

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.. I created a new project and I forgot to import the new plist file and the API key. It was using the old one so that's why it said in the log "marked for deletion"