# Firebase authorization error 17999 happens for 2 users on prod

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

For some very weird reason the issue happens just for 2 users and they are waiting patiently for more than week until we solve it.

[image: Firebase error 17999]

Other users are working like expected, can't reproduce it local either.
For others Facebook authorization works fine, Email and Password works fine as well.
There is nothing special about these users: iOS 11, latest iPhone etc.

Does anybody had chance to investigate and solve the issue already?

P.S. Firebase Support suggested to create minimal reproducible example, but the issue happens just for 2 users and it doesn't look like possible at the moment.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Add a print(error.localizedDescription) within the closure following the facebook login function.

Comment: Thanks, I already have UIAlert with error and localizedDescription. There is the same information like on screenshot. Internal error 17999

Comment: Looks like others had this issue as well [Auth error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634804/google-firebase-authentication-with-email-and-password-does-not-work/38076718#38076718) and [Another error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710339/firebase-unable-to-login-to-facebook-auth). Possibly a corrupted plist file or perhaps the GoogleService-Info.List is outdated or misconfigured.

Comment: @Jay thanks Jay! I saw that answer before. The difference here that my issue happens just for 2 users, for others it works perfect. Also Facebook is configured like it should be.

Comment: Did you capture any device info? Model, iOS version, app version etc? Are they perhaps behind a firewall (wifi) connection? Lot's of variables here that could be causing the error on those specific devices.

Comment: @Jay thanks for suggestion. There is nothing special, they have the latest version from App Store like others, their device show up like “iPhone”. They tried to login with and without Wi/Fi. But there was one successful login after bunch of attempts like one of them said. But now problem is there again.

Comment: hi, @AlexanderStepanov do you know the reason ? I have 15 users have this internal error every day. 

Comment: @JIEWANG these users are from special regions which are blocked by google. VPN on user side solves the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderStepanovThanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens for users in specific regions which are "banned" by Google (like Crimea etc)

Works fine when user turns on VPN. No other workarounds found by me so far.